# Is it safe to copy the binlogs from a running mysql server

Tags: mysql, backup, binlog

I want to backup a tokudb database.

I want to be able to restore it to the most recent state. 
Which I am writing to a file at backup.

My guess would be to run something like this

```
mysql -e "SHOW MASTER STATUS; SHOW SLAVE STATUS; FLUSH LOGS" > mylogposition.log
```

Which will rotate the log files after saving the position?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you have done flush logs and you have taken the logfilename just before flush logs say it should be fine.

Example current binlog file is bin-log00333 and after flush logs it is bin-log00334. You may scp the logs from bin-log00001 to bin-log00333 and don't take bin-log00334.

Answer (score 2):

Is this a Master?  Or a Slave?

`FLUSH LOGS`, by itself, will start new log files.  (Please verify that this happens.)  Then the old files are properly closed and can be copied.  And the `POS` is `0`.  (`4` also works for a binlog.)